# Не могу получить hexadecimal значение Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

У меня есть значения:
Я беру их с телеграм каналов тысчами, в таком виде:

```
https://t.me/proxy?server=185.254.188.78&port=1754&secret=5ddee8e14d4583af36235d5d1c84afea
```

После разделения secret становится в кавычки и с этого все начинается.

```
secret='5ddee8e14d4583af36235d5d1c84afea'

server = '168.119.182.51'
port = 88
secret = 'ee00000000000000000000000000000000646c2e676f6f676c652e636f6d'

    client = TelegramClient(
        num['number'], num['api_id'], num['api_hash'],
        connection=connection.ConnectionTcpMTProxyRandomizedIntermediate,
        proxy=(server, port, secret)
```

Comment: Желательно добавить код, с которым возникли проблемы, и результат который нужно получить (у вас и так hexadecimal изначально, не понятно что должно получиться).

Comment: Теперь он мне пишет  fromhex() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: После чего вам пишет? Вы код добавьте сначала в вопрос.

Comment: Добавленный код не объясняет, откуда вы получили это значение (которое вы к тому же убрали из вопроса).

Comment: `После разделения secret становится в кавычки и с этого все начинается.` - что начинается, ниоткуда появляется набор 16-ричных цифр, и вы начинаете хотеть их преобразовать в число? **Опишите конкретную задачу, которую вы пытаетесь решить.**

Answer (score 2):

```
value = 0xee14057ebf8839b15682b5c558d2f84588646c2e676f6f676c652e636f6d

print(value)
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно преобразовать строку с 16-ричными значениям в набор байт на основе этих значений, можно воспользоваться функцией `binascii.unhexlify`:

```
import binascii

value = 'ee14057ebf8839b15682b5c558d2f84588646c2e676f6f676c652e636f6d'
print(binascii.unhexlify(value))
```

Вывод: `b'\xee\x14\x05~\xbf\x889\xb1V\x82\xb5\xc5X\xd2\xf8E\x88dl.google.com'`

`bytes.fromhex` тоже работает:

```
value = 'ee14057ebf8839b15682b5c558d2f84588646c2e676f6f676c652e636f6d'
print(bytes.fromhex(value))
```

Вывод такой же.

Предополжим что это число (хотя вряд ли, судя по присутствию `dl.google.com`), тогда можно преобразовать в целое с помощью `int`:

```
value = 'ee14057ebf8839b15682b5c558d2f84588646c2e676f6f676c652e636f6d'
print(int(value, 16))
# Вывод: 1643155408172129359520301427715915034326611778413272222625799639797034861

# Проверяем, что это то же самое число, что было:
print(hex(int(value, 16)))
# Вывод: 0xee14057ebf8839b15682b5c558d2f84588646c2e676f6f676c652e636f6d
```

Comment: Это получается мы в байтовую систему переводим

Comment: В байтовое представление. Нет никакой "байтовой системы".

Comment: Я пробовал через hex, но тогда требует строку

Comment: @ДмитрийБовак я не знаю что вы "пробовали" через hex. С hex в ответе - это просто пример, который показывает, что полученное число в 16-ричном виде - это то же самое, что было изначально. Но я на 99% уверен, что на самом деле вам не нужно число. Вы методом тыка пытаетесь что-то получить, не понимая, что вам нужно получить. **Опишите конкретную задачу, которую вам нужно решить полностью в вопросе.**